# Can the number of tables and functions affect performance?

Tags: postgresql, performance, database-size

I have some big database with hundreds of functions and tables.
They also have a lot of sequences, custom types and some views and triggers.

There is a point when the quantity of objects will be a problem? Affecting for example parsing?

Did you ever notice some kind of impact for these reasons?

Comment: This question is too broad. You'll have to give us some idea of your hardware setup in order for any comments to be relevant. 100 tables with 64GB of RAM might not be a problem, but with 30MB, it could be!

Comment: @Vérace: The question is obviously not about table and disk size, but about the effect of many objects. Your comment is more OT than the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a gradual process and the effect is comparatively small. But of course, looking up entries in system tables gets slower with lots of rows. Those are just regular tables. Highly optimized, but regular tables. There are indexes to keep the effect small.

I have never actually noticed an effect in my biggest database with a couple of hundred tables and close to 1000 functions. Sequences, views, triggers .. everything. Your DB seems to have similar numbers - I'd guess you cannot report any observations yourself? Or you would surely have added that in your question.

The cost for other things like backup and `VACUUM` rises, too, obviously.

Comment: Ensure your model is complete and correct and don't worry about the number of objects you create.  The trivial speed up from a small catalogue would be swamped by the ineffecient processing due to a poorly normalised schema.